# Parse list with Moshi without custom adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I use an API which returns data as array, like this JSON string (let's call it "tasks")

```
[
  {"id": "5d9478a643a7520041b367c7",
   "name": "Task 1",
   "value": 2
  },
  {"id": "5d9478a243a7520041b367c6",
   "name": "Task 2",
   "value": 10
  },
]
```

I want to parse this response to a list. So I have created corresponding data class with generated adapter

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Task(
    var id: String,
    var name: String,
    var value: Int
)
```

My retrofit service looks like this

```
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

interface NetworkService {
    @GET("tasks")
    suspend fun tasks(): Response<List<Task>>
}
```

But I want to user a container type, e.g.:

```
data class TaskList(val tasks: List<Task>)
```

as network response result. Is this possible without creating custom adpter or I will need to create a custom adapter and pass it to moshi builder?

Comment: Have you tried to change `Response<List<Task>>` to `Response<TaskList>`?

Comment: @Neo have you tried it by yourself before asking? It won't work, please look at the JSON string, do you see a "tasks" array in it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a specific adapter in order to parse a JSON like this

```
class YourAdapter {

@FromJson
fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader, jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<YourResponse>): List<YourResponse>? {
    val list = ArrayList<YourLResponse>()
    if (reader.hasNext()) {
        val token = reader.peek()
        if (token == JsonReader.Token.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
            reader.beginArray()
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                val yourResponse = jsonAdapter.fromJsonValue(reader.readJsonValue())
                YoutResponse?.let {
                    list.add(yourResponse)
                }
            }
            reader.endArray()
        }
    }
    return list.toList()
}}
```